# Get namespace from class

Tags: typescript, typescript2.7

Is it possible within TypeScript to get the namespace of a class?

```
namespace My.API.DTO {
    export class Something {

        // ID
        public id: number;

        public constructor() { }
    }
}
```

I can write the following to get class name

```
console.log(My.API.DTO.Something.name);
```

Outputs

> Something

I want the output to be

> My.API.DTO.Something

I'm open to using a third party library to help with this. Please note I generate all my TypeScript DTO classes from their C# counterparts using the [TypeWriter](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: you can add a static field ' name'  to your class but as the previous poster wrote, it is not possible using only the typescript compiler.

Comment: TypeWriter lets you customize the generated TypeScript, so it should be easy enough to make it emit the full name of the class as well.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that since you are using TypeWriter. @LambdaFairy's suggestion is both the simplest and the one which will give you the highest fidelity. I will caution you that if you are doing this for serialization, you are making a design mistake.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the information?   Is it strictly for diagnostic/tracing, or something else?   As Aluan mentions, using this for serialization is probably a bad idea?

Comment: @Burt_Harris I want to use it to know what type the object is. I could use TypeWriter but not sure about adding another field to my DTOs just to code around TypeScript limitations.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to the root namespace -- `My` in your case -- you can recursively patch all classes (all functions actually) with a helper method:

```
const patch = (ns: object, path?: string) => {
    Object.keys(ns).forEach((key) => {
        const value = ns[key];
        const currentPath = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            patch(value, currentPath);
        }
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            Object.defineProperty(value, 'name', {
                value: currentPath,
                configurable: true,
            });
        }
    })
}

namespace My.API.DTO {
    export class Something {

        // ID
        public id: number;

        public constructor() { }
    }
}

patch({ My });

console.log(My.API.DTO.Something.name); // My.API.DTO.Something
```

You just have to be aware that this patches any function inside the tree since ES6 classes are nothing more. The drawback is that you'll have to patch each namespace root individually since `patch(window)` will most likely result in a too much recursion error and probably other unwanted side-effects.

Note that instead of using object destructuring you could also call `patch` like this:

```
patch(My, 'My');
```

**[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20patch%20%3D%20(ns%3A%20object%2C%20path%3F%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.keys(ns).forEach((key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20value%20%3D%20ns%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20currentPath%20%3D%20path%20%3F%20%60%24%7Bpath%7D.%24%7Bkey%7D%60%20%3A%20key%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20patch(value%2C%20currentPath)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(value%2C%20'name'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20currentPath%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20My.API.DTO%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Something%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ID%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Apatch(%7B%20My%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(My.API.DTO.Something.name)%3B)**

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, I think the answer is no.  [If you compare your TypeScript code to the compiled JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20My.API.DTO%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Something%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ID%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20s%20%3D%20new%20My.API.DTO.Something()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.writeln(%60class%20name%3A%20%24%7BMy.API.DTO.Something.name%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Adocument.writeln('%3Cbr%20%2F%3E')%3B%0D%0Adocument.writeln(%60constructor%20name%3A%20%24%7Bs.constructor.name%7D%60)%3B), you can see that namespaces are implemented using a fairly standard JavaScript module pattern:

```
var My;
(function (My) {
    var API;
    (function (API) {
        var DTO;
        (function (DTO) {
            var Something = /** @class */ (function () {
                function Something() {
                }
                return Something;
            }());
            DTO.Something = Something;
        })(DTO = API.DTO || (API.DTO = {}));
    })(API = My.API || (My.API = {}));
})(My || (My = {}));
```

Since this is all you have to work with (all TypeScript type information disappears during the compilation stage), I don't think there's any sane* way to work backwards from a class to get its namespace chain.

Depending on your use case, you may be able use something like [class decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) to attach metadata to the class and access it at runtime.  This will only work if you are in control of the classes you want to inspect.

<sup>* It might be possible to recursively loop over all of the objects in the global scope until you find the location of the class's constructor function.
 For example, your `Something` class can be found (in the browser) at `window.My.API.DTO.Something`.</sup>